# install dapr helm chart on a second namespace while already installed on another namespace in same cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, dapr

I am trying to install a second dapr helm chart on namespace "test" while it is already installed on namespace "dev" in same cluster.

```sh
helm upgrade -i --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    dapr-uat dapr/dapr
already installed config exists whith following name:
```

```
NAME                NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                   APP VERSION
dapr                dev         1           2021-10-06 21:16:27.244997 +0100 +01    deployed    dapr-1.4.2              1.4.2
```

I get the following error

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "dapr-operator-admin" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "dapr-uat": current value is "dapr"; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "test": current value is "dev"
Tried specifying a different version for the installation but with no success
```

```sh
helm upgrade -i --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    dapr-uat dapr/dapr \
    --version 1.4.0
```

Starting to think the current chart does not allow for multiple instances (development and testing ) on the same cluster.
Has anyone faced the same issue ?
thank you,

Comment: If the chart installs cluster-global resources then it in fact can't be installed concurrently.  Possibly changing the release name `dapr-uat` in the second installation would help, but it depends on the chart code.  Is the chart one you wrote yourself, or are you just trying to install a third-party chart?

Comment: Using a third party-chart :
https://github.com/dapr/dapr/tree/master/charts/dapr
Yes, changing the name or the version number didn't help solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing dapr chart applies cluster-wide ressources where names are given with no namespace name consideration. So, when trying to install a second configuration, a cluster-wide ressource name conflict occurs with pre-existing cluster-wide ressource:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with update: ClusterRole "dapr-operator-admin" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "dapr-uat": current value is "dapr-dev"; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "uat": current value is "dev"
```

I had to edit the chart:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/dapr/dapr.git
```

I edited RBAC ressources in subchart dapr_rbac where ressource name now considers namespace name in `dapr_rbac/templates/ClusterRoleBinding.yaml`

previous file :

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dapr-operator
...
```

Edit now consists of metadata name on all ressources:

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dapr-operator-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
...
```

Same logic have been applied to MutatingWebhookConfiguration in subchart dapr_sidecar_injector in file `dapr_sidecar_injector/templates/dapr_sidecar_injector_webhook_config.yaml`

For full edits, please see forked repo in :
https://github.com/redaER7/dapr/tree/DEV/charts/dapr